# How to define the type (int) for a new field in SQL SELECT INTO statement in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, select-into

I want to define the new field in a select into statement as integer. However, the NewField ends up as binary. How can I accomplish this?

```
SELECT ExistingField1, ExistingField2, NewField
INTO NewTable
FROM ExistingTable
```

I searched a lot but couldn't find a solution yet.

Edit 1: I am performing the SELECT INTO statement from within the Microsoft Access application itself. (it is not a table in Access that points to a SQL Server table)

Edit 2: NewField is created with the SELECT INTO statement. It does not exist in a pre-existing table.

Comment: This question is currently tagged as both 'sql-server' and 'ms-access'. Are you performing the SELECT INTO statement from within the Microsoft Access application itself? Is [ExistingTable] a linked table in Access that points to a SQL Server table? Where does `NewField` come from? Please edit your question to add these details.

Comment: I edited my question to address the issues you raised

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The reason it ends up as a binary is because the field in the existing table most likely is a binary field.

You could try doing something like this:

```
SELECT ExistingField1, ExistingField2, CAST(NewField AS int)
INTO NewTable
FROM ExistingTable
```

`CAST` does not work in MsAccess. However, this should work:

```
SELECT ExistingField1, ExistingField2, cInt(Field1 + Field2) AS NewField
INTO NewTable
FROM ExistingTable
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. However, I got an error with this: "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'CAST(NewField AS int)'." Addtionally, NewField is not an existing field. It is created with the SELECT INTO statement along with the NewTable. Do I miss sth very basic?

Comment: The new field would still be a result of some kind of operation you perform on existing columns, right? I just Googled and found `CAST` won't work in Access. See my edit.

Answer (score 3):

For Access I would use this, then the parameter dialog does not show.

```
SELECT ExistingField1, cInt(0) AS NewField
into NewTable1
FROM Table1
```

For SQL Server

```
CAST(null AS int) AS NewField
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have structure of NewTable already defined you can try:

```
Insert Into NewTable 
Select 
      ExistingField1,
      ExistingField2,
      cast(NewField as int) as NewField,
From ExistingTable
```